# CloudKit workaround for testing purposes

Tags: calendar, icloud, cloudkit

I am working on a web application using iCloud and the calendar. Is CloudKit necessary? I have seen this API https://github.com/wvrzel/simpleCalDAV but it doesn't seem to work any more (probably). The reason why I am asking for this is because I don't want to pay for something that I am not sure will work as I expected. Can I create testing account for free somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CloudKit is Apple's main means of storing data for apps, so you will need to enroll in the Apple Developer Program to gain access to it.

Comment: I decided to use Google Calendar instead and it works great, it's free and it can be downloaded on iPhone.